# Loan Amortization Schedule - Precision and rounding

Tags: php, domain-model, math, financial

I have been playing around making amortization schedules in PHP. My `php.ini` currently has the precision set to `14`. I understand going into this that there **will be rounding errors** however I am hoping to minimize these errors.

My current way of doing this is only rounding my payment amounts and then leaving all other values at their `php` default precision value. Calculations below:

```
$Term_Rate = $Annual_Rate / $Year_Terms;// annual_rate / terms per year

$Payment = round(( $Term_Rate * $Principle ) / ( 1 - (( 1 + $Term_Rate )**( -$Total_Terms ))), 2 );

if($y%4===0)
    $leap = 1;

$interval = $date_2->diff($date_1); 
$days = $interval->days;

$interest = $days * (( $Annual_Rate * $Principle ) / ( 365 + $leap ));

if($Payment>($Principle+$interest))
    $Payment = round( $Principle + $interest, 2);

$balance = ( $Principle + $interest ) - $Payment;

$Principle=$balance;
```

Then for any values that are displayed back I do my rounding to 2 decimal places. For most of the inputs I have tried the calculator performs well, meaning the loan is paid of on the final payment of the term. However, some input values can cause my loan to be paid off early. Inputs such as:

```
$Pay_Type = "Monthly";
$Principle = "25000000.00";
$Annual_Rate = "0.2";
$Term_Length = "360"; 
$Term_Unit = "Months"; 
$Start_Date = "2020-01-31";
```

Not all of the inputs will be realistic but Im hoping to be able to handle even some of the more obsurred inputs such as a 90% interest rate on $25000000.

Please inform me if more of my code is required or if any calculations are handled improperly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a rounding error, but a wrong application of financial formulas.

The formula used for your loan payment is based on financial math designed for a periodic payment with an interest rate for the same period, assuming [compound interests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).

In your usage of this formula, you base yourself on an annual rate `r`.  You calculate the periodic rate by subdividing it linearly (proportionaly to to nulber of days in the term).So for a monthly term, you are using roughly `r/12` as interest rate.  And this is mathematically not correct in case of a compound interest formula. It's only an [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Approximate_formula_for_monthly_payment).

The right way of finding the term-rate `t` if you have `n` terms per year would be `(1+r)**(1/n)-1`.

You can read more about annual and subannual rates in the wikipedia article liked above, as well as in this wikipedia article about [effective interest rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate) (caution: the formula in that article is the reverse one, i.e. how to calculate the annual based on the exact monthly one).

Let's give some numeric examples for an annual rate r:

- for r=4%  the monthly rate for compound interest is 0.327% whereas your linera calculation would be 0.333%.  The difference is very small, so it's easy to misregard it as rounding issue.
- for r=10% the correct monthly rate would be 0.797% whereas the linear one would be 0.833%.  So the magnitude of the error increases with the rate.
- for r=90% (hope you have better rates ;-) ) it would be 5,4% per month whereas your code would use 7,5%.  So your monthly figures would be based on  rate that is 38% higher than it should be: no wonder that you have significantly shortened the number of terms !

Not related: for the daily calculation of interest rates, depending on the party you represent and your country, the denominator could be 360 or 365 or the exact number of days as you did.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That being the case, wouldnt I also need to alter my interest calculation? If willing, could you share how this would need be altered (still accounting for leap years)?

Comment: @FamousAv8er I've just edited with some more links where you can find this info.  The trick is either to calculate the term rate ax exmplained above, or use another formula for the loan (see wiki article on compund interest, section about exact calculation). The number of days in the year doesn't matter in that calculation, since the rate is annual.  It would matter only if you'd determine the annual rate based on a daily rate.  By the way there are still some banks around the globe that'll calculate using a year of 360 days, and use either 30/360 or even 365/360.

Answer (score 0):

If you care, your calculation for leap years is incorrect. It does find all leap years - 1996, 2000, 2004, but it also will have false positives: 1900, 2100, etc.

```
if (($y % 400 === 0) || (($y % 100 !== 0) && ($y % 4 === 0)))
```

Two references for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341516/how-can-i-write-a-leap-year-program-in-one-line-using-php

https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Come on, bot, really? You want citations for leap years?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252837)